# Compare pipe delimited files and just write mismatching columns to output file

Tags: linux, bash

I have two files 
abc.txt

```
||||||FARGO||916244244||0923206||0923206|00752341039|092320600752341039|09232060075234103900001|WHITE|||||||80903|
||||||JOHN||977428452||0923206||0923206|00752341029|092320600752341029|09232060075234102900001|SHORT|||||||80903|
||||||RIYA||967688294||0923206||0923206|00752341037|092320600752341037|09232060075234103701001|BROOKS|A|||||80903|
```

def.txt

```
||||||FARGOA||916244244||0923206||0923206|00752341039|092320600752341039|09232060075234103900001|WHITE|||||||90001
||||||JOHNA||977428452||0923206||0923206|00752341029|092320600752341029|09232060075234102900001|SHORT|||||||90001
||||||RIYAA||967688294||0923206||0923206|00752341037|092320600752341037|09232060075234103701001|BROOKS|A|||||90001
```

I should be able to compare two files column wise and just write the columns that are mismatching to an output file pipe delimited

Expected output:

```
FARGO|80903  
FARGOA|90001  

JOHN|80903  
JOHNA|90001  

RIYA|80903  
RIYAA|90001
```

Comment: There's no single command that'll do this. Where are you stuck, exactly? Break the problem down and show us what you already know how to do. For instance, do you know how to read pairs of lines from two files in parallel? Do you know how to split those lines into individual columns? Do you know how to loop over those values? Do you know how to compare strings and print out ones that differ?

Comment: I can split the file using awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file1 and awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file 2
after that is there a way i can compare both and write the way i was asking?

Comment: Your output format seems not so useful: Are you expecting that only 2 fields will differ between the 2 files? And always the 7th and 24th fields?

Comment: No, any field can mismatch, i was just giving an example, 
i want to be able to write all the columns from file1 and file2 to output file

Comment: I would suggest this output would make more sense: `1|7|FARGO|FARGOA` -- line 1, field 7, abc value, def value

Comment: Or `FARGO||||||||||||||||||||1234`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this to compare records from 2 files

```
awk  -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
    NR == 1 {print "line","field",FILENAME,compareto}
    {
        getline line < compareto
        n = split(line, ary)
        max = n>NF ? n : NF
        for (i=1; i<=max; i++) if ($i != ary[i]) print FNR, i, $i, ary[i]
    }
' compareto=def.txt abc.txt
```

```
line|field|abc.txt|def.txt
1|7|FARGO|FARGOA
1|24|80903|90001
2|7|JOHN|JOHNA
2|24|80903|90001
3|7|RIYA|RIYAA
3|23|80903|90001
```